# how to make mouseover image appear next to radio selection nicely without buggy bouncing effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got an image to appear when I mouse over a small image next to a text box, but the second image is bigger than the small one and it causes the left one to bounce down when it appears over and over. I'd like both images to appear statically and the second one to appear downward instead of bounce the first one down. I made a jfiddle to demonstrate [this](https://jsfiddle.net/avbnrvhh/1/), and this is my code:

```js
     document.getElementById('imageToHover').onmouseover = function() 
     {
      document.getElementById('imageToShow').style.display = 'inline';   
     }
    
     document.getElementById('imageToHover').onmouseout = function() 
     {
        document.getElementById('imageToShow').style.display = 'none';   
     }
```

```css
 
    #imageToShow
    {
        display: none;
    }
    #imageToHover
    {
        height= "25" width= "25";
        float: top;
    }
```

```html
   
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 



<b>blah blah blah?</b>
        <img id="imageToHover" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/212yolzmnaL._AC_UL160_SR160,160_.jpg" height= "25" width= "25" alt="hover me"/>
        <img id="imageToShow" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/06/8b/50/cb/quality-inn-suites-south.jpg" height= "80" width= "120" alt="image to show"/><br>

        <input type="radio" name="options[]" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="options[]" value="No"> No<br><br>
```

all I could think of was using `float right` to get it to magically appear to the right but it just went to the far right, and I tried using `float:top` on the first image, but didn't do anything.. all I could think of was maybe there was some div magic but every time I use divs it just adds new lines and doesn't put them next to eachother anymore.. can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: You can add ```position: absolute``` styling and additional styling so the small image and bigger one will fit the positions and then small image will fix to it's positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Just added `position: absolute;` to the big image.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('imageToHover').onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById('imageToShow').style.display = 'inline';
  }

  document.getElementById('imageToHover').onmouseout = function() {
    document.getElementById('imageToShow').style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

```css
#imageToShow {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#imageToHover {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js">
</script>

<body>



  <b>blah blah blah?</b>
  <img id="imageToHover" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/212yolzmnaL._AC_UL160_SR160,160_.jpg" height="25" width="25" alt="hover me" />
  <img id="imageToShow" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/06/8b/50/cb/quality-inn-suites-south.jpg" height="80" width="120" alt="image to show" /><br>

  <input type="radio" name="options[]" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
  <input type="radio" name="options[]" value="No"> No<br><br>
</body>
```